# PHP Foreach loop - why does this return the same results?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

this echos the same value over and over. It calls three functions which rely on the variables in the array - what am I missing?

```
$arr = array('LGW','LHR');


foreach ($arr as $airportcode) {


$result1 = fhrxml($airportcode);
$result2 = parkingquotexml($airportcode);
$result3 = holidayextrasxml($airportcode);

$result4 = array_merge($result1, $result2, $result3);


sort($result4, SORT_NUMERIC);
$result5 = reset($result4); // First Element's Value


$price01 = array_splice(explode('<br>',$result5),0,1);  
$price = implode('<br>',$price01);

$name01 = array_splice(explode('<br>',$result5),1,2);  
$name = implode('<br>',$name01);

echo $name;

}
```

Comment: What does `$result5` contain? And what's the current output and expected output?

Comment: $result5 returns the first value of the array produced in $result4 (which is a merged array from the three functions). It should return the name of two airport carparks, but it returns:

Cophall Parking Gatwick
Cophall Parking Gatwick

Comment: What does `var_dump($result5);` output? And which ones are the carparks that should be returned?

Comment: Rephrase: Add `var_dump($result5);` **after** `$result5 = reset($result4);` -- What does it output?

Comment: var_dump returns: string(35) "98.4
Cophall Parking Gatwick
" string(35) "98.4
Cophall Parking Gatwick
"

It should return several car park names, like this: 
Cophall Parking Gatwick
 Purple Parking Longstay

Comment: The issue is probably with your functions.  The code seems to output valid information.  What happens if you manually call the functions (like `echo fhrxml('LGW');echo fhrxml('LHR');`)?

Comment: That just returns ArrayArray. If I swap the array values around it returns the second carpark twice, which is why I thought it was an issue with the foreach loop. Is it perhaps that the $name value gets overwritten every time?

Comment: The `$name` value does get overwritten every time, but it is outputted first.  Sorry, I should have said `var_dump` instead of `echo`.  So, does `var_dump(fhrxml('LGW'));var_dump(fhrxml('LHR'));` return the same values?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that returns the same data 4 times. My function queries and XMl and gets the results via 'return $result03'. Perhaps the issue is bigger than I first thought - any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If your function returns the same value, then the code you posted above is working perfectly.  You should check the code in the functions.  You passed it different data, and got the same result.  If you need help with that code, I suggest starting a different question.